# Why long numeric type seems to be not enough: #VALUE! mistake

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code I wrote to get a sum without duplicate values. I have a table with 1424 rows and 2 columns (string and a value). So I take a look at a previous value and if the current value is not the same, I sum it up.

```
Function sumAll()
Dim firstRow As Long
firstRow = 5
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = 12
Dim aRow As Long

Dim sumResult As Long
sumResult = 0
Dim previousValue As Long
previousValue = -1
For aRow = firstRow To lastRow
        If Cells(aRow, 2).Value <> previousValue Then
            sumResult = sumResult + Cells(aRow, 2)
            previousValue = Cells(aRow, 2)
        End If
Next aRow
sumAll = sumResult
End Function
```

But the problem appears when a make  a `lastRow` as large as 30 - I get a `#VALUE!` mistake. But why? The maximum value `sumResult` might ever achieve is `60 912 997 662`. `Long` is supposed to hold up to [9,223,372,036,854,775,807](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/numeric-data-types).

**EDIT:** Ok, I changed `Long` on `Double` and it still gives me the error:

```
Function sumAll()
Dim firstRow As Long
firstRow = 5
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = 600
Dim aRow As Long

Dim totalDoubles As Long
totalDoubles = 0

Dim sumResult As Double
sumResult = 0
Dim previousValue As Double
previousValue = -1
For aRow = firstRow To lastRow
        If Cells(aRow, 2).Value <> previousValue Then
            sumResult = sumResult + Cells(aRow, 2)
            previousValue = Cells(aRow, 2)
        Else
            totalDoubles = totalDoubles + 1

        End If
Next aRow
sumAll = sumResult
MsgBox ("end: " & totalDoubles)
End Function
```

Comment: This is the second question on this in two days.  Don't read VB.Net documentation and expect it to work in VBA.

Comment: I don't think so. VBA long data type is 4 bytes (-2, 147, 483, 648 to 2, 147, 483, 648). Use Double instead.

Comment: [VBA documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary) on data types - I recommend `Decimal` type which can handle numbers up to `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` with no decimal point (but takes 14 bytes) or `Currency` type which can easily handle 11 digit numbers (and only takes 8 bytes), or - if you are using 64-bit Excel - the `LongLong` type (which is equivalent to the VB.Net `Long`).

Comment: Are all your values in B5:B600 numeric values?  You have no blank cells in that range?  (I assume this is a UDF even though it isn't tagged as such, and therefore your code is crashing somewhere and non-numeric values seem to be the most likely error.)  Step through the code and see what the value of `aRow` is when the code stops.

Comment: @YowE3K, No, thank you. That was the second mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me using Double or Variant. The Long Integer's size is only 4 bytes. The ranges are –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,486,647. Double is 8 bytes and Variant is 16 bytes. This works perfectly for me:

```
Function sumAll() As Variant

    Dim firstRow As Integer: firstRow = 5
    Dim lastRow As Integer: lastRow = 30
    Dim aRow As Integer
    Dim sumResult As Variant: sumResult = 0
    Dim previousValue As Variant: previousValue = -1

    For aRow = firstRow To lastRow
            If Cells(aRow, 2).Value <> previousValue Then
                sumResult = sumResult + Cells(aRow, 2)
                previousValue = Cells(aRow, 2)
            End If
    Next aRow
    sumAll = sumResult

End Function
```

[Here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339929&seqNum=2) you can see the VBA data types' ranges.